# Connection Refused error while fetching data from server in nativescript + Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript

Hello I' m new for Nativescript mobile app development and what i wanna do is that I had created an app and want to connect it to server to fetch some data, I had followed all setps from Nativescript Doc but unable to connect to server. These are my codes please do help me.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { NativeScriptHttpModule } from "nativescript-angular/http";
import { NativeScriptHttpClientModule } from "nativescript-angular/http-client";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { navigatableComponents, routes } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent, navigatableComponents],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
imports: [
    NativeScriptModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    NativeScriptHttpClientModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NativeScriptHttpModule
],
 schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
})
   export class AppModule {}
```

login.component.ts

```
test() {
    this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:60929/ApiTest/Data").subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
}
```

I do get this error

```
System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:113)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:1432)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1390)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1667)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:133)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:466)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:371)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:130)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$Http$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(Async.java:543)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$Http$1.run(Async.java:482)
System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(Async.java:52)
System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
```

M really badly stuck on this

Comment: What if you use IP adress intead of localhost?

Comment: I get "no protocol: 192.168.1.241:60929/api/testapi" error

Comment: With `http://192.168.1.241:60929/api/testapi` ?

Comment: Yes! Actually M trying to connect my real android device while debugging

Comment: I mean, did you try with `http://` at the beginning of the IP address? You error message does not show http. Otherwise, it might just be a proxy issue

Comment: Ohh I got it, added http://, now m not getting that error, but m getting Bad Request - Invalid Hostname error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167975/discussion-between-rohan-sampat-and-david).